How to add the annotation tag in tagged PDF using PDFBox
I have a tagged PDF (PDF-UA compliance) with simple structure:

I need to add the annotation:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/">
      <annots>
        <text color="#FFC333" date="D:20240425000000" flags="print,nozoom,norotate" opacity="0.600000" page="0" rect="43.086,707.79,63.086,732.79" title="ABC">
          <contents-richtext>
            <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
              <p dir="ltr">Sample comment</p>
            </body>
          </contents-richtext>
          <popup flags="nozoom,norotate" open="yes" page="0" rect="595.0,507.78998,790.0,632.79"/>
        </text>
      </annots>
    </xfdf>


in the nested tag Annot in the tag P. Like this (I've made in manually in the Adobe Acrobat):

I'm able to import the XFDF XML into the PDF:
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("tagged.pdf"));
    
    FDFDocument fdfDoc = FDFDocument.loadXFDF(new File("annotation.xfdf"));
    List<FDFAnnotation> fdfAnnots = fdfDoc.getCatalog().getFDF().getAnnotations();
    
    List<PDAnnotation> pageAnnotations = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i < fdfAnnots.size(); i++) {
        FDFAnnotation fdfannot = fdfAnnots.get(i);
        PDAnnotation pdfannot = PDAnnotation.createAnnotation(fdfannot.getCOSObject());
        pdfannot.constructAppearances();
        pageAnnotations.add(pdfannot);
    }
    document.getPage(0).setAnnotations(pageAnnotations);
    
    document.save(new File("tagged_with_annotation.pdf"));

but the veraPDF checker outputs:

An annotation, excluding annotations of subtype Widget, PrinterMark or Link, shall be nested within an Annot tag

and PDF Accessibility Checker (PAC tool) outputs:

Annotation is not nested inside an "Annot" structure element

as expected, because I didn't set the 'annot' tag (and concrete place) for imported annotation.
Also, I'm able to obtain the tag P object:
    PDDocumentCatalog pdDocumentCatalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDStructureTreeRoot pdStructureTreeRoot = pdDocumentCatalog.getStructureTreeRoot();
    COSArray aDocument = (COSArray)(pdStructureTreeRoot.getK().getCOSObject());
    COSObject oDocument = (COSObject) aDocument.get(0);
    COSArray aPart = (COSArray)oDocument.getItem(COSName.K).getCOSObject();
    COSObject oPart = (COSObject) aPart.get(0);
    COSArray aSect = (COSArray)oPart.getItem(COSName.K).getCOSObject();
    COSObject oSect = (COSObject) aSect.get(0);
    COSArray aP = (COSArray)oSect.getItem(COSName.K).getCOSObject();
    COSObject oP= (COSObject) aP.get(0);

But I don't understand how to edit the existing tags tree in the PDF.
Question: how to add the tag and annotation into the existing tags tree into PDF using PDFBox?
UPDATE: the example PDF and XFDF here.
UPDATE 2: I've updated the file tagged_with_annotation_acrobat.pdf on google drive. The previous version was incorrect - missed Annotation tag.
UPDATE 3: To select the last P, change:
COSArray aP = oSect.getCOSArray(COSName.K);

to
COSArray aH1P = oSect.getCOSArray(COSName.K);
COSDictionary oP = (COSDictionary) aH1P.getObject(1);
COSArray aP = oP.getCOSArray(COSName.K);

and for adding the annotation without outer P inside last P
    // add the annotation element
    COSDictionary anDict = new COSDictionary();
    anDict.setItem(COSName.S, COSName.ANNOT);
    anDict.setItem(COSName.P, oP);
    anDict.setItem(COSName.PG, page);
    
    PDObjectReference objRef = new PDObjectReference();
    anDict.setItem(COSName.K, objRef);
    
objRef.setReferencedObject(page.getAnnotations().get(0));
    
    aP.add(anDict);


I've updated the post - link to the example PDF and XFDF added. My main question - 'how to manipulate the existing tags tree programmatically using PDFBOX' - i.e. how to edit/add entry into the tree. May be is there any PDFBox code sample how to do it? Thanks.

"the example PDF and XFDF" - that link opens to an "access denied" message.

@mkl access fixed.

Here's my attempt at this. It is very tailored to your PDF. I have placed the annotation in the array Root/StructTreeRoot/K/[0]/K/[0]/K/[0]/K.
PDStructureTreeRoot structureTreeRoot = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot();
PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
PDAnnotation annotation = page.getAnnotations().get(0);

PDStructureNode documentStructureNode = (PDStructureNode) structureTreeRoot.getKids().get(0);
PDStructureNode partStructureNode = (PDStructureNode) documentStructureNode.getKids().get(0);
PDStructureNode sectStructureNode = (PDStructureNode) partStructureNode.getKids().get(0);

// add a dummy intermediate /P element
PDStructureElement pStructureElement = new PDStructureElement("P", sectStructureNode);
sectStructureNode.appendKid(pStructureElement);

// add the annotation element
PDStructureElement annotStructureElement = new PDStructureElement("Annot", pStructureElement);
annotStructureElement.setPage(page);
pStructureElement.appendKid(annotStructureElement);
// see "Entries in an object reference dictionary"
PDObjectReference objRef = new PDObjectReference();
objRef.setReferencedObject(annotation);
annotStructureElement.appendKid(objRef);

int parentTreeNextKey = structureTreeRoot.getParentTreeNextKey();
PDNumberTreeNode parentTree = structureTreeRoot.getParentTree();
Map<Integer, COSObjectable> numberTreeAsMap = getNumberTreeAsMap(parentTree);
Set<Integer> keySet = numberTreeAsMap.keySet();
if (parentTreeNextKey == -1)
{
    parentTreeNextKey = keySet.stream().reduce(Integer::max).get() + 1;
}
int annotKey = annotation.getStructParent();
if (annotKey == -1)
{
    annotKey = parentTreeNextKey + 1;
    annotation.setStructParent(annotKey);
    structureTreeRoot.setParentTreeNextKey(annotKey + 1);
}
numberTreeAsMap.put(annotKey, annotStructureElement);
parentTree = new PDNumberTreeNode(PDParentTreeValue.class);
parentTree.setNumbers(numberTreeAsMap);
structureTreeRoot.setParentTree(parentTree);

Previous version that uses more of the COS API:
PDStructureTreeRoot structureTreeRoot = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getStructureTreeRoot();
PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
PDAnnotation annotation = page.getAnnotations().get(0);

COSArray aDocument = (COSArray) structureTreeRoot.getK();
COSDictionary oDocument = (COSDictionary) aDocument.getObject(0);
COSArray aPart = oDocument.getCOSArray(COSName.K);
COSDictionary oPart = (COSDictionary) aPart.getObject(0);
COSArray aSect = oPart.getCOSArray(COSName.K);
COSDictionary oSect = (COSDictionary) aSect.getObject(0);
COSArray aP = oSect.getCOSArray(COSName.K);

// add a dummy /P element
// (it later turned out that this wasn't really needed but doesn't hurt either,
// but it was like that in the "good" file I used for inspiration.
// I can remove it if you want)
COSDictionary pDict = new COSDictionary(); // PDStructureElement
pDict.setItem(COSName.S, COSName.P);
pDict.setItem(COSName.P, aSect.get(0)); // assign aP but as ref

// add the annotation element
COSDictionary anDict = new COSDictionary(); // PDStructureElement
pDict.setItem(COSName.K, anDict);
anDict.setItem(COSName.S, COSName.ANNOT);
anDict.setItem(COSName.P, pDict);
anDict.setItem(COSName.PG, page);
// see "Entries in an object reference dictionary"
PDObjectReference objRef = new PDObjectReference();
anDict.setItem(COSName.K, objRef);
objRef.setReferencedObject(page.getAnnotations().get(0));
// not needed here because done in parent; however
//TODO update PDObjectReference API accordingly
//objRef.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PG, page);
aP.add(0, pDict);
    
int parentTreeNextKey = structureTreeRoot.getParentTreeNextKey();
PDNumberTreeNode parentTree = structureTreeRoot.getParentTree();
Map<Integer, COSObjectable> numberTreeAsMap = getNumberTreeAsMap(parentTree);
Set<Integer> keySet = numberTreeAsMap.keySet();
if (parentTreeNextKey == -1)
{
    parentTreeNextKey = keySet.stream().reduce(Integer::max).get() + 1;
}
int annotKey = annotation.getStructParent();
if (annotKey == -1)
{
    annotKey = parentTreeNextKey + 1;
    annotation.setStructParent(annotKey);
    structureTreeRoot.setParentTreeNextKey(annotKey + 1);
}
numberTreeAsMap.put(annotKey, anDict);
parentTree = new PDNumberTreeNode(PDParentTreeValue.class);
parentTree.setNumbers(numberTreeAsMap);
structureTreeRoot.setParentTree(parentTree);

getNumberTreeAsMap is a convenience method found in PDFMergerUtility because the available API doesn't retrieve the whole tree as once.
static Map<Integer, COSObjectable> getNumberTreeAsMap(PDNumberTreeNode tree)
        throws IOException
{
    if (tree == null)
    {
        return new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }
    Map<Integer, COSObjectable> numbers = tree.getNumbers();
    if (numbers == null)
    {
        numbers = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }
    else
    {
        // must copy because the map is read only
        numbers = new LinkedHashMap<>(numbers);
    }
    List<PDNumberTreeNode> kids = tree.getKids();
    if (kids != null)
    {
        for (PDNumberTreeNode kid : kids)
        {
            numbers.putAll(getNumberTreeAsMap(kid));
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}

VeraPDF complains about an incorrect /CIDSet entry, see here on how to fix this

I've now added a dummy /P element. VeraPDF didn't complain about the previous version nor about this one. I don't understand the problem about the Annot tag, because it's there...

Output file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ko9FLcV_u6ObZ8txekKwdDj-5tgutWfz/view?usp=sharing

I realize I misunderstood your second comment to be related to my file because I missed the first comment meaning that you didn't have the file. It turns out both my attempts (without or with the dummy /P entry) pass the test.

@TilmanHausherr thank you! This is what I need! Looks like I have to update your code, because 'Annot' is creating before the tag H1 for the file tagged_with_annotation.pdf.

Then remove the "0," in the add() command. Is that what you meant? If yes then I'll edit it. I had done it this way because your PDF had it this way.

I've put the changed code under 'UPDATE 3' to reflect the needed PDF structure.

No, something wrong. PAC tool now outputs the critical error 'Invalid structure element type.'

Instead of anDict.setItem(COSName.P, aP.get(0)); should be anDict.setItem(COSName.P, oP);. Fixed.
